# How do I get a contact me tool something like Sky has (see details for more info)

Tags: looking-for-a-script, contact-page

How do I get a contact me tool something like Sky has? Sky has a tool where you select a topic, subtopic, etc. [Click here to see this tool.](http://contactus.sky.com/)

Comment: I don't understand the question... Your web developer builds it, I don't think you can get a template for something like this. It could be done client side (Jquery/Javascript etc) or server side. I think it's server side as the page posts back...

Answer (score 1):

It's a form which by the looks of it uses Javascript (including jQuery) to make it, for example, submit the form when you pick a value from the initial dropdown.

You could examine the HTML and Javascript files on the site to work out exactly how it did it, or ask more detailed questions on stackoverflow.com on how to achieve specific things.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to achieve that function with a select menu is to show hide div's based on the selected option. Step two is just a list of articles related to the selected drop down.

[A jsfiddle demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/)

The HTML

```
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>​
```

The jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});​
```